# Swift KeyChain store custom object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, keychain

I'm trying to save something like this:

```
struct User {
    var id: String? = nil
    var name: String? = nil
    var cellPhone: String? = nil
    var email: String? = nil
}
```

Into the `KeyChain`, according to my current project's guidelines, all of these data is sensitive but the email, so I'm trying to store all of these data into the `KeyChain` for this reason.

Is there any way that I can store the whole object? Or should I just trust `CoreData` to store these objects? I need to store them in the device to verify if the user has already registered to skip the registration process and take them to the app's main screen.

I'm using the [`KeyChainWrapper`](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper) methods like this one:

```
let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set("Some String", forKey: "myKey")
```

But if I pass my `User` instance, I get:

`No exact matches in call to instance method 'set'`

Which I believe is because there's no support either from the `KeyChainWrapper` or `KeyChain` itself to save a custom object into it.

Been trying to find what kind of data types we can store inside `KeyChain`, maybe it's just primitives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue, after looking a little bit more into the `.set()` options for the `KeyChainWrapper` I found one for `Data` type.

So, what I'm doing now is:

```
let encodedUser = jsonUtils.encode(object: user)
KeychainWrapper.standard[.userKey] = encodedUser
```

And in my `JSONUtils` class I have `encode` and `decode` functions, so I can convert my `User` into `Data` and viceversa

```
static let shared = JSONUtilities()

func encode<T: Codable>(object: T) -> Data? {
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        return try encoder.encode(object)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}

func decode<T: Decodable>(json: Data, as clazz: T.Type) -> T? {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let data = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: json)
        
        return data
    } catch {
        print("An error occurred while parsing JSON")
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

This way I can store my `User` object securely into the `KeyChain`